# AxisHelper not showing colored

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add an `AxisHelper` to my `three.js` project. I added it like this:

```
axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
scene.add(axes);
```

It gets added, but it isn't colored It's solid white, and therefore hard to see. How can I make it the regular colors?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, axis, renderer;

init();
animate();


function init() {
  container = document.getElementById('container');

  // Camera
  camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / -2, -500, 1000);
  camera.position.x = 200;
  camera.position.y = 100;
  camera.position.z = 200;

  // Scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Axis
  axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
  scene.add(axes);

  // Grid
  var size = 500,
    step = 50;
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  for (var i = -size; i <= size; i += step) {
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-size, 0, i));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(size, 0, i));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, 0, -size));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i, 0, size));
  }
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    opacity: 0.2
  });
  var line = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  scene.add(line);


  // Cubes
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    overdraw: 0.5
  });
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  cube.scale.y = 1;
  cube.position.x = 0;
  scene.add(cube);

  // Lights
  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(Math.random() * 0x10);
  scene.add(ambientLight);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
  directionalLight.position.normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  // Render
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


  // Events
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.left = window.innerWidth / -2;
  camera.right = window.innerWidth / 2;
  camera.top = window.innerHeight / 2;
  camera.bottom = window.innerHeight / -2;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var timer = Date.now() * 0.0001;
  camera.position.x = Math.cos(timer) * 200;
  camera.position.z = Math.sin(timer) * 200;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is a limitation of, or bug in, `CanvasRenderer`. Are you using that renderer for a reason? Otherwise, use `WebGLRenderer`.

Comment: @WestLangley Yes. I'm not using WebGLRenderer, because it doesn't work on chrome. I think I just have to enable WebGL. But if it's not enabled by my browser by default, why should it be enabled for others by default. The average user will not know how to enable it.

Comment: `CanvasRenderer` is slow, and renders with artifacts which may be unacceptable to you. It is also no longer part of the libray - just the examples. Your choice.

Comment: @WestLangley I hear. But shouldn't support be higher priority than speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `CanvasRenderer` to properly render the colored axes of `AxisHelper` like so:

```
var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 );

axes.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( axes.geometry );

scene.add( axes );
```

`CanvasRenderer` has a bug, and does not properly render vertex colors when the geometry is `BufferGeometry`. The above is a work-around.

three.js r.82